# Is there a better way to draw many big UIImages onto a CGContext than CGContextDrawImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I am drawing stuff onto a video, frame by frame.
The video is FullHD and i get my context like this

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

// Lock the image buffer
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);



CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
                                                 8,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

Now i draw my strings which is pretty quick.
But then i have one FullHD size overlay bitmap and several smaller ones that need to be rotated and moved etc.

Right now the `CGContextDrawImage`costs me between 30 and 100 ms each depending on the size. That slows my video processing down to 3 frames per second which is unacceptable.

Unfortunately i am somewhat unexperienced with the whole drawing with objective c thing. I usually rely on UIImageView and UILabel and just add them to a superview and let the OS deal with it, but in this case i need to draw onto the video frame.

The above way is the only one that works for me, but maybe there is a better one ? I just could not find any.

I read that CIImage was faster but only for processing and filtering images and i dont need to do any of that.
Also i read that using OpenGL might be faster but i have never done anything with openGL and this would cost me tremendous amounts of time, that i dont have.

The biggest image is an overlay and it should simply be copied over the video frame. I understand that the alpha values cost some time but all of this is happening in RAM, none of it is displayed. There has to be some faster way to do all this ?

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT, this is how i draw it, its pretty obvious

`CGImageRef cg_mask` is a UIImage converted into video-frame resolution with the video frame byte order and alpha (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst)

i am working with 720 at the moment, but will be fullHD later

`CGRect rect_mask = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 780);`

`CGContextDrawImage(context, rect_mask , cg_mask);`

time for the drawing operation is about 80ms on a iPhone4S

Comment: it is there `CGContextDrawImage`

Comment: "the CGContextDrawImagecosts me between 30 and 100 ms each depending on the size" Could you show some of that code?

Comment: So you are scaling it down? And you are performing that scale operation on every frame, even though it is the same for every frame?

Comment: no, image is scaled down properly at the beginning, the same CGImageRef is used every frame already fitting

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. It's hard for me to see how to make this any faster, then, since CGContextDrawImage is presumably just blitting the bytes into place. But I am no expert on drawing efficiency.